# Using display table or similar, how can I add a break to form another row?

Tags: css, html

I am using `display: table` to make equal rows across a `div`, similar to `flex`. Flex for me at the moment seems far too complicated. Nonetheless, this works OK, but how can I make a break so that it makes another set of 3 underneath?

CSS:

```
#footerArea #footerContent #footerCol {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

#footerCol span {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <footer>
        <section id="footerArea">
            <div id="footerContent">
                <div id="footerCol">
                    <span>
                        <h2>Company Info</h2>
                        Company
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <h2>Company Info</h2>
                        Company
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <h2>Company Info</h2>
                        Company
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </footer>
```

As I said, this works a treat, but if I continue to `span` elements it'll just fit them all on one row.

I would like it to go like so, if possible:

[image: ideal footer layout with break under row]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a table layout, use a table structure. Create another "row" div.

In addition, your HTML is invalid. `span` elements cannot contain block level elements like `h2`. Just use a div.

```css
#footerArea #footerContent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#footerArea #footerContent .footerCol {
  display: table-row;
}

.footerCol>div {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section id="footerArea">
    <div id="footerContent">
      <div class="footerCol">
        <div>
          <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footerCol">
        <div>
          <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask what the `>` means exactly on the line: `.footerCol>div` ?

Comment: It's a direct child selector so it only affects divs that are direct children of that parent div.

Answer (score 1):

With flexbox you can do it like that.

```css
.footerCol {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footerCol > div {
    flex: 1 1 calc(100%/3);
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <section id="footerArea">
        <div id="footerContent">
            <div class="footerCol">
                <div>
                    <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Company Info</h2> Company
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</footer>
```